# Proper deployment and reference to Icon

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, deployment, icons

Using Visual Studio 2010, I have placed an icon (trashcan.png) on a toolbar. No problem with compiling and running. I then compile a deployment project (visual studio 2010 deployment project) and transfer the resulting deployment to another machine. In the second machine, it seems the XAML is unable to find the trashcan.png (which crashes everything).

What is the proper method of deploying an icon, and using it, in the deployment project??

XAML

```
   <ToolBar Grid.Row="3" Name="toolbarPictures" Height="28" ToolBarTray.IsLocked="True">
          .......
       <Image Name="TrashCan" Loaded="TrashCan_Loaded" AllowDrop="True"  Drop="TrashCan_Drop"/>
   </ToolBar>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit: Additionaly, in my effort to fix this, I added a Program File(64-bit) to the system files which I can't remove -- how do I remove it?

Comment: It would help newbees like myself to know why this question was downmarked?

Answer (score 0):

For any newbie (like myself) getting here, this is the short answer.

The deployment project will create the program directory and file structure on the target machine (in my case under the Program Files (x86) directory). When including an icon from the development machine, it needs to be placed on the target machine exactly where it was located on the development machine.

In my case, I initially had my trashcan located at:

```
  b.UriSource = new Uri(@"C:\Phoenix I\Phoenix\Phoenix\Icons\trashcan_empty.png");
```

which my deployment project was not creating. Therefore, I added a subfolder under the Application Folder in the deployment project called "Icons" and copied the trashcan_empty.png image to that subfolder. Then, in the exe code, I changed the above to:

```
  b.UriSource = new Uri(@"\Icons\trashcan_empty.png", UriKind.Relative);
```

All works now.
Why this question was downgraded?